# Visual Studio selectively convert multiple lines of code to a single line - ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper, code-formatting

Let's say I have a trivial if statement as follows:

```
if(a > b)
{
    return false;
}
```

Whilst the above matches my defined coding style perfectly, what I want to be able to do is highlight these 4 lines of code, and then very quickly be convert them into a single line as follows:

```
if(a > b) { return false; }
```

Is there a way of doing this selectively. I do not want to do it throughout the file - only the lines I highlight. In many cases I will want the if statement left on multiple lines.

I have ReSharper if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the [VsVim Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329) and then you can place your cursor on the `if` keyword and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> twice (assuming you are using the Resharper Visual Studio keymap) to select the whole `if` block and then press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join all the lines in to one.

If VsVim is not for you then you could try the [CodeMaid Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496) that adds join line functionality (using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>)

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't the hang of VsVim, but CodeMaid does exactly what I want. I'll play around with the other features of CodeMaid now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom template. Take a look [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Inspection__Creating_Custom_Inspections_and_QuickFixes.html). You can then have the standard Resharper fix for the lines you suggested and apply them where you want.

Comment: It's a nice idea, but it doesn't do quite what I want. I don't want these to be highlighted to me. I just want to convert to single line at the press of a button. I don't want ReSharper to make suggestions.

Comment: After you've created the template you can go to code inspection > custom patterns > search now and check all patterns that you want to replace in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Regex Find `\r\n|\s\s+` and replace with a single space. To automate try something like https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/index.html

Here is my code from that

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;

    if (ts != null)
        ts.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(ts.Text ?? "", @"\r\n|\s\s+|\n", " " );
    }
}
```

add `System.Text.RegularExpressions` to the references